# php XMLreader: editing element attributes & values

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

How I edit the attributes or values of an XML element?

**the file:**

```
<element>
  <apple type="fruit">red</apple>
</element>
```

**XMLreader:**

```
        $xml= new XMLReader();
        $xml->open($file);

        while($xml->read()){
            if($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
                if($xml->getAttribute('type') == "fruit") {

                       //change attr. and values to:
                       //apple = cabbage, fruit = vegetable, red = white

                }
            }               
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in order to edit XML, you must not use a **reader** class ;-)

Instead, take a look at [**`DOMDocument`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [**`SimpleXML`**](http://fr.php.net/simplexml).

Comment: Im using XMLreader to parse html content - and so I don't want to deal with caching issues

Comment: You could use `DOMDocument::loadHTML` to parse HTML content ; and there would be no caching, except if you cache something yourself.